# how to get sql request in symfony 4 api that show only the selected data

Tags: sql, symfony, symfony4

I have to show the list of subCategories which have contains some professionnels.the Object-Relational Mapping between professionnels and subCategories is: ManytoMany.  But in the result I get the subCategories List with an object of all professionnels related.
I want to show the list of subCategories with only the clients selected.
How to do it please?

```
/* @QueryParam(name="professionnels", default="", description="")
 * @Rest\View(statusCode=Response::HTTP_OK, serializerGroups={"subCategory", "Default"})
 * @Rest\Get("/subCategory/all")
 */
 public function getAllSubCategoriesAction(Request $request, ParamFetcher $paramFetcher)
 {   
   $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
   $professionnels  = $paramFetcher->get('professionnels');
   $where = false;
   if (!empty($professionnels)){
     if (!$where) {
       $queryBuilder->leftJoin('a.professionnels', 'c')    
                    ->where('c.id IN (:professionnels)')
                    ->setParameter('professionnels', $professionnels);
     } else {
       $queryBuilder->leftJoin('a.professionnels', 'c')    
                    ->andWhere('c.id IN (:professionnels)')
                    ->setParameter('professionnels', $professionnels);
     }

        $params['professionnels'] = $professionnels;
        $where = true;
    }
    if(!empty($params)){
      $queryBuilder->setParameters($params)
                ->orderBy('a.name');
    } else {
      $queryBuilder->orderBy('a.name');
    }

    return $queryBuilder->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to explicitly use `select()` method of the `QueryBuilder::class`.

Example:

```
$queryBuilder->select('c.id', 'c.name') // Only these columns will be selected
    ->leftJoin('a.professionnels', 'c')
    ->where('c.id IN (:professionnels)')
    ->setParameter('professionnels', $professionnels);
```

https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/query-builder.html

You can use `select()` like this `select('a', 'c.id', 'c.name')` which will select everything aliased as `a` and only designated `u.` columns.

Comment: No problem. If it helped you, you can accept it as a solution (tick the green check mark) :)